# INotifyPropertyChanged in a Model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

In [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvvm/mvvm_first_application) tutorial `INotifyPropertyChanged` is in Model - not in ViewModel.

Is it correct and acceptable?  What are standards ?

Comment: Wy minus ??  It is very relevant question not only for me - for all beginners

Answer (score 7):

`INotifyPropertyChanged` is just an interface that provides functionality, it's not MVVM specific in any way. Classes generated by Linq to SQL or the like also usually implement it for example.

Comment: It's also worth noting it exists in `System.ComponentModel` in `System.dll`, just to emphasise the fact it's not tied to any UI framework.

Answer (score 2):

It is correct! You should raise PropertyChanged where you change the property (so in the model in your case). In other cases it might be in the view model but it can really be anywhere.

I think the confusion starts because the properties in the view model must raise the PropertyChanged event to update the UI. That does however not mean that the PropertyChanged event must have its origin in the view model.